# What's the equivalent for while (cin >> var) in python?

Tags: python, c++, input

In online contests, when the length of input is not specified and reading the input file directly through the program is not possible, one can use this code in C++:

```
while (cin >> var)
{
    //do something with var
}
```

What's the equivalent for python?

- Without using any file-related function such as `open() write() ...`

Comment: You can call `input()`/`raw_input()`, but that's more like `cin.getline()`.  I don't think there's a direct equivalent to the extraction operator.

Comment: There's also `for line in sys.stdin: ...`, but again, that's certainly not a direct equivalent to the extraction operator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no direct equivalent in Python. But you can simulate it with two nested loops:

```
for line in sys.stdin:
    for var in line.split():
```

If you need something other than a string you'll need to convert it in a separate step:

```
        var = int(var)
```

Answer (score 3):

This could be helpfull.

```
import sys

for line in sys.stdin:
    #Do stuff
```

Comment: That's not the same - `std::cin >> var` expects type-compatible input with `var`; `line in sys.stdin` is clearly not the same (`var` could be `int`, `char`, `std::string`, ...)

Answer (score 1):

In C++ `cin >> n` has a dual nature: It acts both as a **boolean expression** indicating whether it has read (true) or has not read (false) an element in the sequence, and as a **"channel in"** operator that gets an element (if there are any left). Sadly, in python the closest you can get right out-of-the-box is to doing `n = input()`, which also acts as a "channel in" *BUT does not act as a boolean expression*.

In order to solve that (by making things "C++onic" instead of "Pythonic") you could define an auxiliary function called, conveniently, `cin()`. This function will have one parameter `n`, which will actually work as if it was a C++ pass-by-reference (i.e. an input/output parameter). To simulate that behaviour, here I make `n` to be *a list object with one element -in this case an integer number-*, taking advantage of Python list's aliasing properties. This way, when `n[0]` changes in the auxiliary method, the value change will also be reflected in the main method `n[0]` value each time `cin(n)` call returns true... without any further do.

```
def cin(n):
    #function that woks equally to doing cin >> n
    try:
        n[0] = int(input())
        return True
    except:
        return False

def main():
    #C++ like main method (for illustrative/comparative purposes)
    n = [0]
    while cin(n):
        #MESSAGE: do someting with n[0] (watch out, n is list object with one element)

main()
```

For example, in the previous code, if you wanted to print the double of the elements of a sequence of numbers with an indefinite number of them, you would simply change the line #MESSAGE for the following:

```
print(n[0]*2)
```

Or, another example, if you wanted to implement a recursive solution to print in inverse order the elements of a sequence (also with indefinite length) and having the constraint of NOT using a list with more than one element you would, again, need to change the line #MESSAGE for the following:

```
main()
print(n[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

A crucial functionality of `std::cin` is that [it skips whitespace](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/skipws) (competition programming problems are space and newline separated for this reason). I suggest reading and processing one line at a time like the other answers suggest, but it is possible to use [`str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) in a generator to *simulate* reading one number at a time like C++ `std::cin >> n` usage:

```
import sys

def stdin_gen():
    for x in sys.stdin.read().split():
        yield int(x)


cin = stdin_gen()

x = next(cin)
y = next(cin)
print(x, y)
```

Answer (score 0):

write the following code

`while True:
 a=input()
    if(a==''):
       break
    else
      .....`
   .

in else part you write the code which wants to execute
and if you want to use int in your code convert it in int and use that